# Coding this equation in R

Tags: r

Please help, I am new to R. How to code this equation in R programme using loop for and while?

[image: Please help, I am new to R. How to code this equation in R programme using loop for and while?]

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `while` loop like below

```
x <- c(1, 5, 2)
n <- 4
while (n <= 77) {
  x <- append(x, log10(x[n - 1]) + x[n - 2] + sqrt(x[n - 3]))
  n <- n + 1
}
```

and you will get

```
> x[77]
[1] 519.329
```